# Change DIV Class on Anchor Click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've seen a few similar posts but I don't have much of an understanding of Javascript so I'm wondering if you can help.

I have the following code, which when a main menu link is clicked (e.g. `#contact`) changes the CSS Class of `<div class="contact">` and adds a few extra classes in order to make the previous page disappear and the new page reappear:

```
$('.top-menu').on('click', 'a', function(){

    /* vars */
    var width = $(window).width();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var h = parseFloat($(id).offset().top);
    var card_item = $(id);
    var menu_items = $('.top-menu li');
    var menu_item = $(this).closest('li');
    var d_lnk = $('.lnks .lnk.discover');

    if((width >= 1024)) {
        
        /* if desktop */
        if(!menu_item.hasClass('active') & (width > 1023) & $('#home-card').length) {

            /* close card items */
            menu_items.removeClass('active');
            container.find(card_items).removeClass('animated '+animation_in);

            if($(container).hasClass('opened')) {
                container.find(card_items).addClass('animated '+animation_out);
            }

            /* open card item */
            menu_item.addClass('active');
            container.addClass('opened');
            container.find(card_item).removeClass('animated '+animation_out);
            container.find(card_item).addClass('animated '+animation_in);
            
            $(card_items).addClass('hidden');
            
            $(card_item).removeClass('hidden');
            $(card_item).addClass('active');
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to tweak this code so that any link with a `changepage` class will also have the same behaviour?

And as a further improvement, is it possible to get this function to happen based on the current page URL/on page load, so that it happens if a user gets sent to the contact page of the website (so they don't have to click the contact page, it would just automatically load).

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: using page here is a bit confusing ! Is it a "one page" design? so divs are just toggling based on their appropriate anchors.. right? Or it's just an extra question to preload the menus..?

Comment: I think I'd change your callback into a separate function, then you can use `$('.top-menu').on('click', 'a', callback)` and `$('.changepage').on('click', 'a',callback)`. Or maybe just `$('.top-menu,.changepage').on('click', 'a',function(){....})` but I'm not super familiar with jQuery, so I don't know if you use multiple selectors together like that .

Answer (score 0):

Please try to fix if statement with below(remove !):

```
if(menu_item.hasClass('active') & (width > 1023) & $('#home-card').length)
```

These code lines are strange each other:
id is getting jquery object, then it goes into $().
This makes conflict.

```
var id = $(this).attr('href');
var card_item = $(id);
```